# Send image inline in email using Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, email-attachments

I am working on `rails 2` application with sending `email` functionality. Now, I need to send `inline image` with the email.

I am using `Mailer` to send email. I tried lots of time using different ways but not succeed to send image inline in email. Below code i am using to send email.

```
# Controller
Mailer.delivery_my_opinion_reply(user, my_opinion, answer)

# Model / Mailer.rb
def my_opinion_reply(user, my_opinion, answer)
    @subject      = "My opinion"
    @from         = "#{Settings.site_name}"
    @recipients   = user.email
    @content_type = "multipart/alternative"
    @attachments.inline['test.jpg'] = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/public/system/att_images/728/original/ball1.jpg")
    @body         = {:question => my_question, :user => user}
  end
```

I got error `"undefined method inline for nil class"`

Comment: Use gem 'roadie-rails' for that. I think it'll help.

Comment: I am using Rails 2 and this gem for Rails 3+.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

> @attachments.inline['image.png'] = File.read("app/assets/images/image.png")
>
> mail(to: email, subject: "subject", content_type: "text/html")